# load DLL from archive

Tags: c++, dll

I am currently writing an application and I want to make it as extensive as possible for me -> every component should be considered as an extension except core functionality.

Basically I provide abstract class which needs to be implemented (header file) and a static library. Also I provide `.py` file with abstract class and example of `.component` file which is basically `.ini` file - there user should declare what's the `class_name`, `python_class_name` and etc.

So in the end user need to create DLL, python script, .ini file. Then zip into an archive with extension `package`. Well that's the plan.

My application is supposed to look for `.package` file, unzip it, get from there `.component` file, read it, load class from DLL by name, create object and store it in global object register inside application. Then I create `c++` and `python` bridge (knowing what interface is implemented by `python` class helps a lot) which allows to invoke `python` methods by name. That `python` script should be store into `zip` too.

I've got basically two questions:

```
1. Is it possible to load DLL from `.zip` in runtime? I believe its hardly possible without creating temporary unzipped file and then deleting it.
2. Is there other to load DLL except basic approach with `windows.h` header? I use `boost` library there and there, maybe there is some way to do it?
```

For zipping as far as I know there no better solution then using `zlib` so I am planning to use that.

Answer (score 2):

1. It is possible to load DLL from zip/memory. Actually many exe packers/virus do load the dll manually.
2. It is actually the same question of the first question.

What LoadLibrary does?

> ```
> Mapping or loading the DLL into memory.
> Relocating offsets in the DLL using the relocating table of the DLL (if present).
> Resolving the dependencies of the DLL, loading other DLLs needed by this DLL and resolving the offset of the needed functions.
> Calling its entrypoint (if present) with the DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH parameter.
> ```

You could write your own code to load the library manually. However, if you do not load the dll the same way as LoadLibrary does, there could be some limitations.

refer: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/430684/Loading-Win-DLLs-manually-without-LoadLibrary

Comment: So there is no way to pass WinApi

Comment: Definitly, you could write a wrapper on winapi or load it manually by using other lower level WINAPI. To my knowledge, there is no loadlibrary wrapper in boost.

Comment: I see... Hm...maybe it's better to unpack and then delete? I may accept maybe using `loadlibrary` but I don't want to touch WinApi more then that...I want to leave that monster alone

Answer (score 2):

You can load .dll library from memory, at least with trivial .dll without more dependency.

What you do is to emulate what LoadLibrary do. Parse the PE executable yourself, call VirtualAlloc, setup proper page attributes, copy the payload, do relocations, and lookup the symbols.

A quick search reveal a detail yet simple tutorial [here](http://www.joachim-bauch.de/tutorials/loading-a-dll-from-memory/).

Note that this may also upset certain virus scanner.